# Error in polygonising raster data with QGIS on Mac

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, polygonize

I'm using QGis Chugiak on a Mac and I'm trying to converting a raster layer in a vector data by: Raster/Conversion/Polygonize. So, I select the layer needed from the drop-down menu, I give a name to the output, layer but every time an error heppens. 
Probably there's something that doesn't work in GDAL.
I leave there the error informations:

[image: Error in polygonising a raster]